# How to bypass CloudFlare rocket script if wp_enqueue_script is used to add scripts?

Tags: php, wordpress, cloudflare, rocketscript

I just googled this but didn`t retrieve any specific info. I have such code on a PHP template for WordPress:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-carousel', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js', array('jquery'),'',true); ?>
```

And I want to add CloudFlare ignore for Rocketloader `data-cfasync="false"` just before the 'src' attribute of jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js

What can I do?

Regards

**Edit:**

A big thanks to @Mary for the code. So the solution for this is to add this function in functions.php :

```
function add_data_attribute( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
    if ( 'jquery-carousel' !== $handle )
       return $tag;

    return str_replace( ' src', ' data-cfasync="false" src', $tag );
}

add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_data_attribute', 10, 3 );
```

If there is a need to add more tags like 'jquery-carousel1', 'jquery-carousel2' to this function, the code looks like this:

```
function add_data_attribute( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
    if( ! in_array( $handle, array( 'jquery-carousel', 'jquery-carousel1', 'jquery-carousel2' ) ) )
       return $tag;

    return str_replace( 'src', 'data-cfasync="false" src', $tag );
}

add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_data_attribute', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try filtering with [script_loader_tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/).

```
function add_data_attribute( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
    if ( 'jquery-carousel' !== $handle )
       return $tag;

    return str_replace( ' src', ' data-cfasync="false" src', $tag );
}

add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_data_attribute', 10, 3 );
```

This way you can target your specific enqueued script.

Comment: Thanks Mary, this really helped me.

Comment: One more thing is if I want to add more to the list - how can I edit the if ( 'jquery-carousel' !==$handle ) and add here also others like - 'jquery-ui-script' and 'jquery-tools-forms-script' ? How do I add multiple tags there?

Comment: You could condition if the handle doesn't exists in an array of handles. `if( ! in_array( $handle, array(  'jquery-ui-script', 'jquery-tools-forms-script' ) ) )`

Comment: Thank you for helping out, this worked! I will update the function for others to see it.