# How to disable Cloudflare's Rocket Loader for specific scripts? Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cloudflare, rocket-loader

I'm trying to disable Cloudflare's Rocket Loader for specific scripts. At first I'm trying to disable it for mobile slider. I tried various combinations of this (and every other I found on StackOverflow) code:

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', function ( $tag, $handle ) {

    if ( 'writeup-owl-carousel' !== $handle )
        return $tag;

    return str_replace( "type='text/javascript' src", ' data-cfasync="false" src', $tag     );
}, 10, 2 );
```

This script is responsible for the element that I'm trying to exclude from rocket loader:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'writeup_scripts' ) ) {

    function writeup_scripts() {

        wp_enqueue_script( 'writeup-owl-carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/owl.carousel.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'', true );
    }  
}
```

When I paste this code in functions.php, the whole element (slider) dissapears. Does anyone know what's wrong with this code? I feel like I've tried everything...

Comment: Try removing `type='text/javascript'` from the first code snippet and check again.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't changed anything. The slider still dissapears :(

Comment: Got any other ideas?

Comment: Is the script being enqueued on your site? If so, is it getting the `data-cfasync` property or not?

Comment: Yes, the script is being enqueued on my site. How can I check if its getting the data-cfasync property?

Comment: Just check the source code of the page :P

Comment: I think so then :) I found this in my source code: type='text/javascript' data-cfasync="false" src='https://example.com/min/b3895.js'></script> - there's the slider code inside that minified file. I dont know why there's still "type='text/javascript' - I removed it from that code, just like you said. That's strange.

Comment: If I had to guess: caching. Do you have a caching plugin installed on your site? If so, it might be a good idea to disable it while you're developing stuff.

Comment: This is not cache-related. I purge cache every time I make any change. I use LiteSpeed cache. Do you have any other ideas? This is really strange - I really feel like I've already tried everything. When I paste the same code on a website that doesn't use Cloudflare (same theme, same plugins etc - clone of my main site), the slider works fine so the code must be affecting with Cloudflare.

Comment: Apparently, this should help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42888777/1836697

Comment: You may prefer to create a page rule... https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169436-How-can-I-have-Rocket-Loader-ignore-specific-JavaScripts-